# selenium RC basic test doesn't work with iexplore, but works with FF, and more

Tags: java, selenium-rc

The classic google test here from selenium website, it works in FF on vista. On IE7, apparently doesn't find the window object. Selnm gets farther in the test (On IE) when I change config to using "*iexploreproxy", (instead of "*iexplore") but I cannot use that because it causes untrusted security certificate warnings. I installed selenium RC 1.0.1, and checked it is running on my box, I am not using any other tools such as bromine. I am running on Eclipse.

public class NewTest extends SeleneseTestCase {

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    setUp("http://www.google.com/", "iexplore");
         // We instantiate and start the browser
  }

  public void testNew() throws Exception {

       selenium.open("/");
       selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
       selenium.click("btnG");
       selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
       if(! selenium.isTextPresent("Results * for selenium rc"))
           throw new Exception("failed");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I found this error to occur when IE was running in protected mode.  You can disable protected mode by going to IE Tools->Internet Options->Security and click the check box.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the internet options, connections, LAN settings has a automatic configuration script/custom profile that was interfering somehow in IE. It works now! 
Here was the path just for history.
file://C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/customProfileDir4b9b53c99d684ec4952cf8a721790c85/proxy.pac

Comment: I'm pretty sure that .pac script is from going into the iexploreproxy mode.